# How to implement an async pipe in html but still be able to call functions when data is returned

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-5

I've implemented an async pipe in angular 5.  It works as expected but I would like to be able to call a few functions and assign variables when data is returned from the backend (i.e. set seo details, ads targeting, )

Without using the async pipe I made the call to the service like this:

```
    this._dataService.send(new BrochureRequest(this._stateService.params.propertyId)).subscribe((httpResponse) => {
     this.httpResponse$ = httpResponse;
        // do more stuff
     });
```

However, with the async pipe I don't see how I have the option of doing anything to the return data in the typescript.

This is how I've implemented the async pipe :

**typescript**

```
this.httpResponse$ = this._dataService
      .send(new BrochureRequest(this._stateService.params.Id));
```

**html**

```
 <div *ngIf="httpResponse$ | async as httpResponse; else loading">
       {{httpResponse | json}}
 </div>

 <ng-template #loading>
     loading ...
 </ng-template>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of RxJS are you using?

Comment: @ConnorsFan 5.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tap operator

> The tap operator is useful for side effects or changes that don’t
>   relate directly to the returned value of the Observable

```
this.httpResponse$ = this._dataService
          .send(new BrochureRequest(this._stateService.params.Id)).pipe(tap(data=> console.log(data)));
```

Comment: 'tab' rather than 'tap'? or 'map'?

Comment: Tap typo mistake sorry about that